# LibGDX public sprite batch for the entire application

Tags: java, android, object, memory-management, libgdx

The question at hand here is whether it is a good idea to have one public SpriteBatch in the Game class, which is then used by all Screens. This would avoid reallocating objects whenever the active Screen changes.

However, I see people using new and private SpriteBatches in each and every Screen. Why do people do this? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a single `Batch` instance is advised, but I don't think public (or static) variables are a good idea, since they break the encapsulation and make it harder to refactor the code. Imagine moving the screen class to another application: you would have to replace all references to the batch in your `Game` extension or you'd be forced to create such field in yet another project.

Instead, I'd pass the batch in screen constructor. Screens are for displaying views, after all: no need to inform them about the rest of the application.

Answer (score 1):

You're right. They should not be doing that. You can make it `final` if you want to protect it a bit. All objects that use it should know to set the parameters that they need, such as applying their own projection matrix and blend mode.